# asp.net mvc Send form from site to email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my mvc site, it looks like

[image]

I created model for my form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ComponentTrading.Web.Models
{
public class FeedbackForm
    {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created view for my form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" }))
                    {
                    <fieldset>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @Value = "Name" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @Value = "E-mail" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @Value = "Phone" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow"})
                    <input class="form-button" data-type="reset" value="Clear" />
                    <input class="form-button" data-type="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

}

and now i try to do a sending a letter to email, but it doesn work, when I push "send-button" it happens nothing and I dont get email

my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contacts()
    {
        FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
        temp.Message = "Message";
        return View(temp);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
    {
        string Text = "<html> <head> </head>" +
        " <body style= \" font-size:12px; font-family: Arial\">"+
        Model.Message+
        "</body></html>";

        SendEmail("mironny@inbox.ru", Text);
        FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
        return View(temp);
    }


    public static bool SendEmail(string SentTo, string Text)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("Test@mail.ru");
        msg.To.Add(SentTo);
        msg.Subject = "Password";
        msg.Body = Text;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);



        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("TestLogin", "TestPassword");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        //client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
// if you dont pass any parameter
// BeginForm posted to the action that
// has name as view name.
// so no need to write any parameters
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
}
```

OR

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contacts", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" }))
{
    ...

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
}
```

You have a few question about mvc and there is more important thing of them is incorrect overload methods. My suggestion, first, you should learn html-helpers overload methods. And MVC model binding strategies...

Comment: I tried the second code, but it doesnt work again, when I push "send-button" it happens nothing and I dont get email and fields dont become clear although I wrote `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
        {
            string Text = "<html> <head> </head>" +
            " <body style= \" font-size:12px; font-family: Arial\">"+
            Model.Message+
            "</body></html>";
            
            SendEmail("mironny@inbox.ru", Text);
            FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
            return View(temp);
        }`

Comment: Where is the submit button? Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have submit-button, I just forget to copy it here, I added clear and send buttons in my question.

Comment: It looks no problem, debug it and try to handle what is the error. I m sorry, I cant see any problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! I found a mistake in my code, and now I when I push "Send"-button I get 404 Error /HomeController/Feedback not found, but I cant understand why if I have `[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Feedback()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)
        {...}` at my HomeController ?

Comment: Maybe the reason is I have not `input` but `a` for submit at my form `<a href="#" class="link1" onclick="document.getElementById('feedback-form').submit()"><em><b>Send</b></em></a>` ?

Comment: In your Form URL you dont need write `HomeController` just write `Home` I mean no need to write `Controller` suffix for every URL in MVC.

Comment: Also there is no method that is named `Feedback` in your HomeController. If you want to post form to `Home/Contacts` then your beginForm should look : `Html.BeginForm("Contancts","Home",.....)` and your generated URL will look : `Home/Contacts`.

Comment: yes, yes, I got it, and I did that, but my form doesnt work in any case.

Comment: May be you can open a new question with all new code blocks. So, not only me, all SO users will see your question. And you can solve it more quickly...